# Is there a way to show multiple subtitles at same time with videojs?

Tags: video.js

I am working on a project with which needs multiple subtitles to be showed at same time. And I am using videojs as my player.

Is there anyway to show multiple subtitles at same time with videojs?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "at the same time" ?

[image]

If this is what you try to do: having multiple subtitles for one video (but you can display only one at a time), here's how to do it.

```
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="669" height="376" poster="img.jpg"> 
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="captions" src="subtitle1.srt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
    <track kind="captions" src="subtitle2.srt" srclang="ar" label="العربية"></track>
    <track kind="captions" src="subtitle3.srt" srclang="es" label="Español"></track>
    <track kind="captions" src="subtitle14.srt" srclang="fr" label="Français"></track>
</video>
```